# I'm building an iframed Facebook Site. Will all tabs be viewable on mobile including Blackberry?

Tags: facebook, iframe, mobile, tabs

Do I have to optimise the site in a certain way? Does it need to built in HTML5 or another specific way?

It appears at present, only the full version of the sites allow you to view page tabs and applications and at the moment you can only view the wall, info and photos.

Would anyone be able to advise me on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Facebook fan pages are currently only available on the full Facebook.com site.  They aren't available via the Facebook mobile site, Facebook touch site, or the native Facebook clients.  Mobile phones and tablets can access the full site, but by default they open up to the mobile/touch sites so you probably won't see much traffic if any from mobile devices to your fan page.  Mobile web and app users will instead currently get your fan page wall, not your custom tab.